# How to handle server/connection exceptions with React and Redux thunk in a maintainable manner

Tags: javascript, ajax, exception, reactjs, redux

I'm using Redux thunk to dispatch asynchronous actions like fetching and posting to server. Each action creator call returns a promise, which resolves when after ajax has done it's magic and Redux has actually dispatched the correct action to update the state according to success/failure of ajax. This way we can customize the post-dispatch callback at component level.

```
doPostActionCreator(data) {
  return dispatch => {
    return httpService.post(data) {
      .then(response => {
        dispatch({type: POST_SUCCESS, data: response})
        return response
      })
      .catch(error => {
        dispatch({type: POST_ERROR})
        return error
      )}
    }
  }
}
```

--

```
componentsDoPostHandler(data) {
  this.props.doPostActionCreator(data)
    .catch(error => {
      alert(error)
      this.setState({...})
    })
}
```

Everything is fine with this simple example, but when I try to introduce real error handling logic by this pattern, like calling componentsDoPostHandler recursively from within catch, and breaking when counter limit exceeds, things start to look ugly, hard to maintain and easy to break. What makes thinks even more complicated, in my real world scenario, `this.props.doPostActionCreator` is actually an callback of `fetchCsrfTokenActionCreator`, which itself needs same error handling logic, trying to fetch X times and doing something else if that fails. Now, if one page contains two different containers, and they both introduce this logic, it's a whole mess of latter's recovery actions getting dispatched after first one has already performed the recovery, as it's not possible to cancel once called action creator. In the end, it's hard to read how the program works and "out of sync" action problems starts to emerge, rendering application in inconsistent state, and those problems are hard to track.

This makes me wonder, if returning a promise from action creator is actually an anti pattern, which eventually leads to unmaintainable code. I didn't find any real world examples how to deal with asynchronous service errors using React/Redux stack. Am I doing it wrong? Is there a cleaner way to handle asynchronous exceptions (ideally trying X times, alerting user and returning to login page) keeping everything consistent, easy to understand, maintain and avoiding asynchronous mess?

Any real world example about the topic would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can handle all of your retry logic within the action creator itself. That is to say, I don't think you need to return anything to attempt to call `.catch()` from your component, or wherever you're calling the action creator. Remember that you also get access to a `getState()` method within a thunk, so say in your action creator's `.post().catch()`, you can always dispatch something to indicate something has failed, which could perhaps be handled by a reducer which tracks number of failures, and then after the dispatch call `.getState()` to see how many failures there were and decide what to do from there (ie try again, or perhaps dispatch another action indicating that something has failed too many times, which would update your state and allow your components to render from that state).

I think by not worrying about `.catch()` outside of your action creators you will simplify the problems you are seeing. You could perhaps abstract this out to an API caller method that handles this logic for you, if you wanted it to occur in several action creators.

Comment: yep in general I use this pattern.  My thunks don't ever return anything.  My components just call the action creators in a "fire and forget" manner and never try to do anything with a return value from an action creator.  The failed promise updates Redux state with the failure.  The component will see this failure state and can then issue more actions if it wants.  Or you can have the thunk do the retrying internally...it could even take additional arguments that the component provides when calling the action creator that tells it how to handle retry.

Comment: How would I ensure using this method that concurrent fetches running in different pace doesn't result in situation where error state set by first failing fetch leads to login page, state is cleared and after that the second fetch hits and fails, messing up the state consistency. I heard about Redux Saga to interrupt actions but don't want to introduce yet another framework. Also, what is good practice to actually check and handle the error state in Redux? General upper level PageComponent perhaps, which would render FailComponent on error, which on mount dispatches return to login action?

Comment: Addition to previous: I'm concerned that any presentation component doesn't try to render after fetch failure, as they try to access map and other functions of data that doesn't exist at that point

Comment: I suppose you could set some kind of flag indicating that you are at a login screen, and then check for that when a request finishes to ignore the result. In that way when the first request redirects to login the other requests just silently fail. In terms of handling the error I would often just set some kind of general error message flag which would pop up a modal, for example, and get cleared out when the modal is dismissed. If you want to do a redirect because the error is because of being logged out you could do that too.